# Auto layout and using values calculated during animations

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I have a view (let's call it A) which I animate by changing it's height constant within an animateWithDuration block, and it has a subview (B) that is pinned to it's bottom. Is it possible to set the position of B before A finishes animating using A's final height value? I.e. is it possible to use A's final point before it actually animates to it?

Code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ....
    viewA.addSubview(viewB);
    [viewA addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:viewB attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:viewA attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f]];
    ....
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed
{
    ....
    //Here I want Auto Layout to immediately set viewB's final position, even though it relies on a's height constraint which is being animated
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^
    {
        viewAHeightConstraint.constant += 50.0f;
    }];
    ....
}
```

Comment: Did you try using A's height value? It should reflect the A's final value even while animating

Comment: What do you mean by "use"? You know where we are going so you can do anything you want. Show your actual code / screen shot.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, let me rephrase the question: is it possible to make Auto Layout set the final position of B automatically whilst the property of it's superview A that it relies on is being animated, or would I have to set it manually?